# reactjs event handler miss this

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

when i change the input value, the event handler onChangeEvt will lose 'this'...

how i can get helloworldComponent instance in event handler?

```
<!--lang:javascript-->

import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
    onChangeEvt(e){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this))             //undefined
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <input onChange={this.onChangeEvt}/>
            </div>  
        )
    }  
}  
ReactDom.render(
    <HelloWorld/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `this` variable. There are three ways to do this:

1) Use arrow functions. They implicitly bind to the outer `this` variable. (My preference.)

```
<input onChange={(event) => this.onChangeEvt(event)} />
```

2) Explicitly use `function#bind`:

```
<input onChange={this.onChangeEvt.bind(this)} />
```

3) Bind your methods in the constructor:

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.onChangeEvt = this.onChangeEvt.bind(this);
}
```